# Get vertex with particular edges - remove duplicates

Tags: graphql, gremlin, tinkerpop

I need to export vertex with some of connected to it. Without any projection - just as it is (like a data dump).
What I want to achieve is to remove redundant vertices in result (json document).
Let assume there is a graph structure:

```
g.V().has('id', '000-000').as('a').out().as('b').out().as('c').select('a','b','c')
==>[a:v[1],b:v[4],c:v[5]]
==>[a:v[1],b:v[4],c:v[3]]
```

I'd like to get result in format like:

```
==>[a:v[1],b:v[4],[c:v[5], c:v[3]]]
```

If there will be more `b` or `c` vertices, something like that:

```
==>[a:v[1],[b:v[4],b:v[7]],[c:v[5], c:v[3], c:v[9]]]
```

Just to make output data (in json) smaller.

Currently I'm getting something like that:

```json
[{
    "a": {},
    "b4": {},
    "c5": {}
},
{
    "a": {},
    "b4": {},
    "c3": {}
}]
```

And would like to have:

```json
[{
    "a": {},
    "b": [
        {b4},
        {b4}
    ],
    "c": [
        {c5}, 
        {c3}
    ]
]}
```

Which operators should I use to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the `project()` step in Gremlin.  If you want a list of values in each field, you can use `fold()` to put them into a list.  Example:

```
g.('000-000').project('a','b','c')
     .by()
     .by(out().fold())
     .by(out().out().fold())
```